# Accesing to canvas as property from class works only for second object

Tags: javascript, class, canvas

I'am working on simulation of train station control panel. I created canvas with map of station and interactive elements. I decided to create class with signals for trains to save lines of code. It looks like this:

```
class enterSignal{
    constructor(status, position, x, y, canvas){ //status and position are not used yet
        this.ctx1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.ctx1.beginPath();
        this.ctx1.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.ctx1.fillStyle = "rgb(109, 109, 109)";
        this.ctx1.fill();
    } 
    goAhead(){
        this.ctx1.fillStyle = 'green';
        this.ctx1.fill();
    }
}
```

The `goAhead()` method changes color of `ctx1` canvas to green (go ahead signal for train driver). The main problem is when I create two objects of `enterSignal` class and run `goAhead()` method for single object it works only for last object. For example:

```
var enterSignal1 = new enterSignal("red", "left", 50, 190, canvas);
var enterSignal2 = new enterSignal("red", "right", 930, 150, canvas);
enterSignal1.goAhead();
```

It affects on enterSignal2 instead of enterSignal1. 
So where is the problem?

Comment: Both objects refer to the same canvas, and a canvas can only have one 2d context. So `enterSignal1.ctx1` and `enterSignal2.ctx1` are the same.

Comment: So, how can I separate this?

Comment: Use multiple canvases, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, but I've got one canvas with map and objects inside it and I think creating more canvas isn't good

Comment: I think you may need to redraw the element with the new color.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way...
just like they mentioned in the comments, we re-draw the element.

```js
class enterSignal {
  constructor(color, x, y, canvas) {
    this.ctx1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.draw(color)
  }
  draw(color) {
    this.ctx1.beginPath();
    this.ctx1.arc(this.x, this.y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this.ctx1.fillStyle = color;
    this.ctx1.fill();
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var enterSignal1 = new enterSignal("red", 10, 10, canvas);
var enterSignal2 = new enterSignal("red", 20, 30, canvas);
var enterSignal3 = new enterSignal("red", 30, 50, canvas);
enterSignal1.draw("green");
enterSignal2.draw("yellow");
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```